# Airflow up and running but no DAG-s in UI

Tags: airflow

I’m running Apache airflow on my local Windows 11 machine. Airflow processes are up and running and Airflow UI is accessible through localhost:8080 address.

[image]

I have also DAGs file (tuto.py) in dags folder but I can’t see any DAGs via the Airflow UI. I have restarted the Airflow webserver but without success. Any ideas what’s wrong with that?

[image]

The contents of tuto.py DAG file:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your airflow.cfg and the logs you have while starting airflow ?

Comment: Airflow.cfg file:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y-qcrCwcMwzlBtPJoqxZYfE4rJ8owepSDJ5XM3CAaxI/edit?usp=sharing

Airflow startup logs:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cmk6q6m2KWgkGuE2Dn8B12lRP-EEotC3JavTS8Htkqs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: are you using docker-compose ?  if it's the case, please share it also. it looks like the mapping between your local dags directory and docker airflow one is not matching

Comment: Here is the docker-compose.yaml file that I was using:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ajwspBj9sO0yGxnz0dNmsfhPHULDawNBujAfVAN6TTU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have added an answer to your question, could you test it ?

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose file, you mentioned that your dags are located in: `opt/airflow/dags`

```yaml
volumes:
   - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
   - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
   - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
```

Either you put your dags in `/opt/airflow/dags` instead of `docker-airflow-master/dags` or you change the location of dags directory.

If your docker-compose.yaml file is under my_project/docker-compose.yaml, your dags directory must be under: my_project/dags/dag1.py

dags directory and docker-compose file must be in the same level.

Comment: I changed the DAGs path in 'docker-compose.yaml' file from './dags:/opt/airflow/dags' to './dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags' and now I can see the 'tutorial' DAG (tuto.py) in web UI. But why it is so that when I add new DAG file (tuto2.py) to my 'C:\docker-airflow-master\dags' folder, it again doesn't appear in web UI (also changed the DAG ID from 'tutorial' to 'tutorial2' in tuto2.py file)? Restarted Airflow many times but no help.

Comment: you have to delete and create a new image I think.